# Feature '1a33a234-b4a4-4fc6-96c2-8bdb56388bd5' Pivot?

Tags: powerpivot

> Feature '1a33a234-b4a4-4fc6-96c2-8bdb56388bd5' for list template
>   '10002' is not installed in this farm.  The operation could not be
>   completed.

I'm trying to figure out why I'm receiving this error message.

Can someone give me a a hint?

Comment: Well, have you had PowerPivot and then uninstalled it? If so, take a look here: http://whitepages.unlimitedviz.com/2012/09/troubleshooting-and-removing-a-failed-installation-or-upgrade-of-powerpivot-for-sharepoint/

Comment: I've run into this error when upgrading a site. The error happens when the feature is listed in the content database but isn't installed as a solution on the current farm. If that's the case, the easiest fix is to deactivate and uninstall the solution BEFORE attempting to upgrade the site/content db. Of course, depending on what it is, that may or may not break some functionality in the site.

Answer (score 0):

> When you uninstall your solution and you deploy new one vsewss
>   generate new ID for your features. Since SharePoint works with IDs and
>   has no semantic level to understand the features.
>
> If you have a feature that is dependent on another feature.
>   SharePoint will look for the dependent feature ID and will raise the
>   error. The reality is that the feature is installed but has the old
>   feature ID.
>
> Solution:
>
> 1)      Go to the concerned feature in the 12 or 14 hives, you must
>   know which feature is concerned with that functionality.
>
> 2)      Change the feature ID to the one raised in the error
>
> 3)      stsadm -o installfeature -name  -force
>
> Test:
>
> Try to access the functionality it should work
>
> //Note: The above solution works when users are using vsewss

[Source](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/689e22ed-9ec9-46ae-b704-b0684a76f72a/feature-for-xxxxxxxx-list-template-xxx-is-not-installed-in-this-farm-vsewss?forum=sharepointdevelopmentlegacy)

Have a look at the following links also,

1. http://www.sharepointnoob.com/2012/03/21/error-feature-gui-list-template-xxx-installed-farm-operation-completed/
2. http://blog.myitechnology.com/2009/06/fixing-feature-guid-for-list-template.html
3. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2261512
4. http://www.spsdemo.com/Lists/Features/DispForm.aspx?ID=258
5. http://powerpivotgeek.com/2010/06/14/uninstalling-powerpivot-does-what-arg/

**EDIT:**

You could try the below too,

> There are a few things you can try. However, do take a backup of
>   database before doing anything.
>
> 1) Try using the feature admin tool on codeplex site to remove this
>   orphan feature. then try accessing the libraries.
>
> 2) if there are not much number of affected libraries, recreate the
>   libraries and move the data using explorer view or buklk copy tools on
>   codeplex. there are many alternative if one does not work. you can use
>   manage content and structure or even the SharePoint Manager tool to do
>   this.
>
> 3) Forcefully deactivate the feature using stsadm -o deactivatefeature
>
> 4) if everythhing fails a bit of more advanced thing needs to be done.
>   Create a feature.xml with same feature id as in the error not bound to
>   any of the manifests. This would be a dummy kind of a feature and
>   would do nothing except for activating itself and deactivating itself.
>   Once this is done and the feature.xml if created then try to
>   deactivate this feature forcefully. The status of this would
>   deactivated but since the id of a feature doing nothing is used  it
>   would not affect the farm. it just turns off the status of the
>   list/web/site using the feature. Ideally you would not need to get
>   this far.

[Source](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/308fae76-a822-45b8-97cd-64f43ef21d11/feature-guid-for-list-template-101-is-not-installed-in-this-farm-the-operation-could-not-be?forum=sharepointadminprevious)